# When to use res/xml vs.res/layout folders in Android

Tags: android

I am creating preferences for my app and noticed some examples store the XML in res/layout and other store them in res/xml.  Is there a reason or best practice to store them in one vs. the other ?  I already have a bunch of layout files in my res/layout folder, so does it make sense to put the preference layout files in res/xml ?

Comment: Preferences = res/xml ;
Other layouts = res/layout

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Prefereces xmls should be placed in res/xml folder. res/layout is only for layout xmls.

Comment: But isn't the xml for preferences also considered layout?  Its layout for the preferences UI activity.

Comment: when  you create custom preference with custom layout only then your that will be a layout and can be placed in res/layout

Answer (score 5):

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) is from Google.

use res/xml/ for arbitrary XML files that can be read at **runtime** by calling Resources.getXML().

Answer (score 2):

Best practices for Preference XML file location must be as stated [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html): "You must save the XML file in the res/xml/ directory. Although you can name the file anything you want, it's traditionally named preferences.xml".

Although I could not find verification, the custom namespace for your application is the package name specified in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mydomain.app"`

You can use this namespace for custom XML attributes that reference custom controls and preferences. For example, include something like this in the XML file:

`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:myname="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mydomain.app"`

In this same XML file include some custom component:

```
    <com.mydomain.app.MyListPreference
        android:key="pref_item1"
        android:title="@string/item1" 
        android:summary="@string/pref_mysummary"
        myname:someAttr="500" />
```

The someAttr still needs to be defined within the values folder in an attr.xml file.  The attr is declared within a style for the component as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="com.mydomain.app.MyListPreference">
        <attr name="someAttr" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable> 
</resources>
```

In the class that defines the custom component or preference you get the attributes using:

```
mDefaultValue = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(
"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mydomain.app", ATTR_DEFAULT_VALUE, 50);
```